# how can I force PostgreSQL foreign key the same length as primary key?

Tags: database, postgresql

I can do the following DDL in PostgreSQL 9.6

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."bar" (
"bar" varchar(10) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "bar_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("bar")
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."foo" (
"foo" varchar(5) COLLATE "default",
CONSTRAINT "foo_foo_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("foo") REFERENCES "public"."bar" ("bar") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Can I force foreign key the same data length as primary key?e.g. I want the second DDL fail since foo is varchar(5) and bar is varchar(10)

Is the same in other databases?

Comment: What do you mean by "force"? Would you like to get an error for the second statement because it does not use `varchar(10)`? That is not possible.

Comment: You could create a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html)  and use that instead of `varchar(10)`

Comment: _SQL schema validation_ is what you are looking for.

Comment: BTW: the same goes for int fields: an integer FK can reference a bigint.

Comment: And, similarly: a date FK can reference a timestamp.

Comment: @joop I don't think is a good idea to allow so

Comment: @JoopEggen is there a tool called "SQL schema validation"?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to mention the keywords for an internet search.

Answer (score 0):

I will use domain to ensure all fields are the same
thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name